# Divide two records in teradata sql and print one record

Tags: sql, teradata

I need divide two records from a table in sql query
I have a the next records in a table

Table1

```
Id    field1  field3
1     20      20161001  
1     35      20161101
2     20      20161001
2     30      20161101
5     19      20161001 
5     33      20161101
```

(Please notice that the dates in  the example are 2016-**OCT**-01 and 2016-**NOV**-01)

I neeed a sql query that shuld next result:

```
Id   fieldnew
1    0.75
2    0.5
5    0.7368
```

For calculate the"fieldnew" the rule is:
Id 1 example

```
(35 ÷ 20) -1 = 0.75
```

Field1 from field3 with date 20161101 ÷ field1 from field3 with date 20161001 - 1 of record with id 1

Could you help with thw query for obtain the result required please

Comment: I removed the `oracle` tag as you explicitly state Teradata in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Oracle

```
select      id
           ,round
            (
                            min (field1) keep (dense_rank last  order by field3)
                /   nullif (min (field1) keep (dense_rank first order by field3),0)
                -   1   
               ,4
            )      as fieldnew

from        mytable

where       field3 in 
            (
                add_months (trunc (current_date,'mm'),-2)  
               ,add_months (trunc (current_date,'mm'),-1)
            ) 

group by    id
;
```

or

```
select      id
           ,round
            (
                            min (case when field3 = add_months (trunc (current_date,'mm'),-1) then field1 end)
                /   nullif (min (case when field3 = add_months (trunc (current_date,'mm'),-2) then field1 end),0)
                -   1   
               ,4
            )      as fieldnew

from        mytable

where       field3 in 
            (
                add_months (trunc (current_date,'mm'),-2)  
               ,add_months (trunc (current_date,'mm'),-1)
            ) 

group by    id
;
```

---

```
+----+----------+
| ID | FIELDNEW |
+----+----------+
| 1  | 0.75     |
+----+----------+
| 2  | 0.5      |
+----+----------+
| 5  | 0.7368   |
+----+----------+
```

#### Teradata

```
select          id

               ,1.0000

            *   last_value (field1) over
                (
                    partition by    id
                    order by        field3
                    rows between    unbounded preceding 
                                and unbounded following
                )

            /   nullifzero (field1)

            -   1   as fieldnew

from        mytable

where       field3 = td_month_begin (current_date) - interval '2' month
         or field3 = td_month_begin (current_date) - interval '1' month 

qualify     field3 = min (field3) over (partition by id)
;
```

or

```
select          id

               ,1.0000

            *   min (field1) over
                (
                    partition by    id
                    order by        field3
                    rows between    1 following
                                and 1 following
                )

            /   nullifzero (field1)

            -   1   as fieldnew

where       field3 = td_month_begin (current_date) - interval '2' month
         or field3 = td_month_begin (current_date) - interval '1' month 

from        mytable

qualify     field3 = min (field3) over (partition by id)
;
```

---

```
+----+----------+
| Id | fieldnew |
+----+----------+
| 1  | 0.7500   |
+----+----------+
| 2  | 0.5000   |
+----+----------+
| 5  | 0.7368   |
+----+----------+
```

Comment: There a lot of variations. The ideal solution depends on your exact data

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
with
--  start of test data (not part of the solution)
     table1 ( id, field1, field3 ) as (
       select 1, 20, 20161001 from dual union all 
       select 1, 35, 20161101 from dual union all 
       select 2, 20, 20161001 from dual union all 
       select 2, 30, 20161101 from dual union all 
       select 5, 19, 20161001 from dual union all 
       select 5, 33, 20161101 from dual
     ),
--  end of test data (not part of the solution)
     prep ( id, field1, lag_field1, field3 ) as (
       select id, field1, lag(field1) over (partition by id order by field3), field3
       from   table1
       where  field3 in (20161001, 20161101)
     )
select id, round(field1 / lag_field1, 4) - 1 as fieldnew
from   prep
where  field3 = 20161101
;

ID   FIELDNEW
--   --------
 1       0.75
 2        0.5
 5     0.7368
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following solves the problem:

```
select id,
       (max(case when field3 = '20161101' then field1 end) /
        max(case when field3 = '20161001' then field1 end)
       ) - 1 as fieldnew
from table1 t1
group by id;
```

This is using conditional aggregation to get the values.

Comment: Are you assuming the table will have data for just two months? And yes, the table is ordered - by field3. And the growth MAY be negative. The OP said very clearly, take the value for 20161101 and divide that by the value for 20161001, not Max divided by Min.

Comment: @mathguy . . . The field3 values all looked the same to me when I read the question.  I now see the difference in the dates and adjusted the answer.

Comment: Thank for your solution, but nevertheless thebtabke "table" is dinamic for the following month the value of records of the field "field3" changing, the next month the rule is:

Comment: Select the last 2 motnhs in base of current date